# Split screen over two separate application windows

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, autoit

Using Robot Framework with AutoIt and Sikuli I need to use two elements at the same time (application and a folder). How can I split the screen in two to be sure they appear fully visible rather than partially covering one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW LEFT</kbd> the application is pushed to the left hand side of the screen. Then focusing the other application, using <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW RIGHT</kbd> will do the same for the right hand side of the screen.

Now you have your screen divided over two applications.